# List does not exist error at top of page

Tags: list

I put a linked list on our SharePoint front page then another admin deleted the list.  Now I'm am getting this error message at the top of the page and cannot edit that area on the page.  Any ideas how I can get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without restoring the list, you can remove the webpart via the [WebPart Maintenance page](http://www.spdeveloper.co.in/tipsntricks/pages/opening-webpart-maintenance-page.aspx).

> Instead of going to the Edit Properties form of the page, we can easily open the WebPart Maitenance page by just adding the following query string to the page URL
>   ?contents=1
>    So, if your page URL is 'http://yourserver.com/pages/default.aspx' then after appending the query string it should look like ' http://yourserver.com/pages/default.aspx?contents=1'

Answer (score 0):

If you have admin rights, you can restore the list from the recycle bin (or have the other admin do it for you), make the changes to remove the error, then re-delete the list (if that is your end goal). Might be an easier way to do it, but this is just off the top of my head.